# Keycloak Huge JWT Token of master admin

Tags: jwt, keycloak, access-token

We have a realm per customer, multi-tenant architecture. (Expected to have around 500 realms) There is a service account we use, a client in the master realm that will manage the customer realms. The problem is the huge JWT token for the master realm admin user/service account, who manage all the realms that increases in size as the number of realms increases. This is due to the 20+ client roles of each new realm. What are the different options we have to keep the token size low?

**EDIT**:
ps: Reducing roles is not an option either. The service account is an admin of the keycloak admin portal and needs to manage all the realms, so it needs manage-realm etc roles for all the realms. Keyclaok admin portal will not for example allow to delete the realm if it doesnt have delete-realm role.

Comment: You may not be able to have that many realms and still have keycloak perform acceptably fast. Test it out. It becomes unusable with 200-300 realms for us. There is PR to fix that in their code line but I don’t suspect it will get merged any time soon. It’s a big change

Comment: Here is the bug for that https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-4593

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the size of the token you can use the following strategies:

- restrict the roles that the client access;
- use client scopes to narrow down the claims that will be added to the token.

For the first option, you can go to the client in question, tab `Scope`, disable `Full Scope Allowed`, and then choose only the roles that the client is really interested.

For the second option, you can go to `Client Scopes`, create a `scope`, save it, then go to the `Scope` tab, add the roles that will be part of that scope. Then everytime you make a request for a token to the client in question you can send the scope as a parameter of that request. This way you will only include in the token the roles that belong to that scope.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running into this https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-1268.

If you look through the discussion there you will see

> Tokens created for admin-cli or security-admin-console no longer have
> any roles embedded within them. The Admin REST API now checks the
> "aud" claim. If the audience is one of those clients, then it ignores
> claims in token and just accesses the UserModel directly to determine
> if admin has specific permissions.

Use admin-cli or security-admin-console for your client_id. Otherwise you will get every role there is for every realm there is in your token.

In order to use either one of those clients with a token request, you have to make it confidential and enable Direct Access Grants.

Then something like this will work and give you a managable token

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
   -d "grant_type=password" \
   -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
   -d "client_secret=<admin-cli-secret>" \   
   -d "username=my_admin_user" \
   -d "password=<my_admin_user_password>" \
 'http://master.foo.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```